Problema en las importaciones de los módulos de Python en Visual Studio Code
tengo un problema con mi entorno de Python en Visual Studio Code, las importaciones no se quieren realizar a pesar de tener instalado python de manera local y el pip. Ya lo he intentado instalar (pip install ..) desde la consola local pero tampoco funciona, ni aplicar reinicios.

Espero poder importar las librerias.

Visual Studio Code no es más que un editor de texto con colores bonitos. No sé si por defecto está preparado para saber de dónde importar cosas de python, personalmente solo lo uso para TypeScript, y SIEMPRE con las extensiones adecuadas para que el motor de TS funcione correctamente. Así que mi duda es, tienes instalada alguna extensión de Python? Ten en cuenta que VSC NO es un IDE, es un editor de texto. Te sugiero que mires algún vídeo de cómo usarlo para lo que quieres y veas lo que necesitas configurarle y añadirle.

El código y los errores van como texto. No todo el mundo tiene una pantalla 4K para analizar imagenes.

Hola, te recomiendo colocar el código en formato de texto para que otros usuarios puede fácilmente copiar y pegarlo, si les interesa ayudarte.

ten en cuenta que Visual Studio Code, no es un IDE, y por ende depende de plugins y configuraciones para entender que el lenguaje tiene una sintaxis con dependencias de librerías. aqui podras encontrar un tutorial sobre como prepara VScode para programar en python: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Fijate en que ruta se instalaron las librerias y configurar esta ruta en visual studio code para que pueda leer correctamente. Visual Studio Code es un editor, hay que tener habilitada la extension de Jupyter e inicializarla para trabajar con Pyhton y como dijeron los demas, por favor lee las condiciones para preguntar, ya que al ser una imagen se complica entender, ademas ni siquiera se ve si esta correctamente seleccionado el interprete de Python. Saludos
